# Add PDF to Image ReportViewer

Tags: c#, pdf, reportviewer

I am trying to print an RDL report with terms and conditions PDF.  The problem is that the report itself is a Queue of images, whereas the T&C's are in PDF format.  So whenever I do an "Enqueue", adding to the streams, it's looking at that PDF like one big image, as opposed to two pages. This causes a GDI+ generics error.  Is there anyway for me to convert the PDF into the proper image format so that I can combine these documents?  Here's the code I have so far:

```
internal static void DoPrintInvoice(int orderID, SalesOrderBLL.DocumentType doctype, string printer, int copies, List<string> lines)
    {
        using (var context = rempscoDataContext.CreateReadOnlyContext())
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("DoPrintInvoice()"))
        {
            //Customer Opt-Out

            // Generate Report
            using (var report = GetSalesOrderReport(orderID, _DocumentTypeDescriptions[doctype], doctype != DocumentType.InvoiceLetterhead, lines))
            {

                // returns queue of streams.
                var streams = PrintingBLL.RenderStreams(report, landscape: false);
                // returns byte array
                var TermsAndConditions = GetTermsAndConditions();

                //convert byte array to memory stream.
                var TCStream = new MemoryStream(TermsAndConditions);

                //conditional to add T&C's to stream.
                if (doctype == DocumentType.OrderAcknowledgement)
                {
                    streams.Enqueue(TCStream);   
                }

                ParallelInvoke(
                        () => SaveSalesOrderPDF(orderID, doctype, report),
                        () => PrintingBLL.PrintStreams(streams,  string.Format("Sales Order ({0})", report.DisplayName), printer, copies, false)
                        );
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to convert the terms and conditions into an image, and back to a byte array but it gives me the same GDI generic issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at PDFSharp? I have had good luck working with it in the past for rendering PDFs.

www.pdfsharp.com